# What's causing this unpredictable OpenGL bug?

Tags: c++, opengl, gpu

I have an OpenGL test application that is producing incredibly unusual results. When I start up the application it may or may not feature a severe graphical bug.

It might produce an image like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6RxI.jpg

Or like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoUc7.jpg

Or just the correct image, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKNa1.jpg

The scene consists of one spinning colored cube (made of 12 triangles) with a simple shader on it that colors the pixels based on the absolute value of their model space coordinates. The junk faces appear to spin with the cube as though they were attached to it and often junk triangles or quads flash on the screen briefly as though they were rendered in 2D.

The thing I find most unusual about this is that the behavior is highly inconsistent, starting the exact same application repeatedly without me personally changing anything else on the system will produce different results, sometimes bugged, sometimes not, the arrangement of the junk faces produced isn't consistent either.

I can't really post source code for the application as it is very lengthy and the actual OpenGL calls are spread out across many wrapper classes and such.

This is occurring under the following conditions:

- Windows 10 64 bit OS (although I have observed very similar behavior under Windows 8.1 64 bit).
- AMD FX-9590 CPU (Clocked at 4.7GHz on an ASUS Sabertooth 990FX).
- AMD 7970HD GPU (It is a couple years old and occasionally areas of the screen in 3D applications become scrambled, but nothing on the scale of what I'm experiencing here).
- Using SDL (https://www.libsdl.org/) for window and context creation.
- Using GLEW (http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for OpenGL.
- Using OpenGL versions 1.0, 3.3 and 4.3 (I'm assuming SDL is indeed using the versions I instructed it to).
- AMD Catalyst driver version 15.7.1 (Driver Packaging Version listed as 15.20.1062.1004-150803a1-187674C, although again I have seen very similar behavior on much older drivers).
- Catalyst Control Center lists my OpenGL version as 6.14.10.13399.

Comment: I don't think this is a great question for SO if it's not possible to distill it to a small amount of code. One possibility that comes to mind is that you might have missed to clear the depth buffer.

Comment: Are you overclocking your video card?  It's already glitching in other software so it is likely the culprit.  It's also possible the CPU is sending data to the card too fast, causing some of the data to become corrupted.  Try reducing the clock speed of the CPU.

Comment: I'll attempt to create code that produces the bug in a single function. I feel however, given the fact that this bug has shown up in 3 separate implementations of this and is so unpredictable, that it is some underlying issue not a mistake in the code. (Also I am clearing the depth buffer during glClear).

Comment: I'll drop my clock speed and see if that makes any change. My video card is running at entirely stock settings as when I overclock it it becomes highly unstable and generally just crashes any 3D application running on it.

Comment: Dropping the clock speed to 4.0GHz had no effect, going lower than 4 didn't seem to sit well with the CPU so I was unable to test lower frequencies.

Comment: I suggest running this on another computer. Possible causes could be: bad RAM, driver bugs. Do you use texture arrays or 3D textures by any chance? I've ran into driver issues for ATI with those that produce similar errors. But I agree with the other comments: it's just guesswork without code. My bet is bad RAM, because of this statement: "occasionally areas of the screen in 3D applications become scrambled".

Comment: I'm not really convinved that this is a HW issue. It looks just like undefined behavior on the application side to me. There are lots of ways to produce such results. Without the code, nobody can tell. "given the fact that this bug has shown up in 3 separate implementations of this and is so unpredictable, that it is some underlying issue not a mistake in the code" is also a bit naive, especially when it's stated in the question that "I can't really post source code for the application as it is very lengthy and the actual OpenGL calls are spread out across many wrapper classes and such".

Comment: You have a fair point, I tried to re-create the bug in a single function last night and the result was the same exercise but fully functional, it never bugged. That said I also sent the executable to two people who could not replicate the bugs no matter how many times they ran it. I suspect the code plays some part in the likelihood of the bug appearing but the fundamental issue is my GPU.

Comment: @user573949: I can't of course rule out any HW issues. One thing I would probably do in your situation is running the app through [apitrace](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace) and trying to reproduce the behavior there. And I would try to repeadetly replay the traces to see if any trace original recorded as "correct" would turn into faulty results, and also the other way around. Replaying the traces on other machines could also be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a broken graphics card to me. Most likely some problem with the memory (either the memory itself, or some soldering problem). Artifacts like those you see can happen if for some reason setting the address for a memory operation does not fully settle or happen at all, before starting the read; that can happen due to a bad connection between the GPU and the memory (solder connections failed) or because the memory itself failed.

Solution: Buy new graphics card. You may try out what happens if you resolder it using a reflow process; there are some tutorials on how to do this DIY, but a proper reflow oven gives better results.

Comment: I believe you are correct, I sent the executable to two other people and it worked flawlessly on their machines. Looks like a new GPU it is then...